# Chrome - global keyboard shortcut not actually global.

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing an extension with a shortcut key that processes a next action. I declare it in manifest.json

```
"commands": {
      "perform-next": {
        "description": "Performs the Next action",
        "suggested_key": {
          "default": "Ctrl+Shift+0"
        },
        "global": true
      }
```

It properly shows up under Keyboard shortcuts,and it works in Chrome, Windows desktop, and some programs, but fails in other programs like Photoshop. No competing program is using the key combination. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be this: **Chrome cannot read keyboard shortcuts for applications running as Administrator, unless Chrome is also ran as administrator.** Is your Photoshop or other problem applications running as administrator?

I learned this in figuring out why Google Play music shortcuts weren't working in Steam games.

Comment: OK your right my photoshop is running as administrator. But how do I fix the extension?

Comment: You can't. It's not an issue with your extension, it's part of Windows Security. Some googling says its at least since Windows 7. It looks like there may be ways to [sign an executable](http://blog.danskingdom.com/get-autohotkey-to-interact-with-admin-windows-without-running-ahk-script-as-admin/) to get around it, but with your extension you can't change Chrome itself. It's just a limitation your going to have to accept.